# Using process.exit in Google Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'd like to know if using `process.exit()` is a valid way (or good idea) to stop the execution of a Cloud Function. It allows one to write slightly cleaner code, in that you don't have to explicitly return from the exported function.

```
exports.myFunction = function myFunction(req, res) {
    const abort = function(err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).send();
        process.exit(1);
    };

    doSomething(err => {
        if (err) abort(err);

        res.status(200).send("Success!");
    });
};
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Was looking for this myself, found my answer in Google Documentation.  Essentially you want to just exit from that export function and the way in which to do so depends on it being a http or background function.

Http: [Function execution timeline](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#function_execution_timeline)

```
exports.afterResponse = (req, res) => {
    res.end();
};
```

Background: [Terminating background functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background#terminating_background_functions)

```
exports.helloPromise = data => {
    return fetch(data.endpoint);
};
```